# IOS: Swift: Append String to a file

Tags: ios, string, file, swift, append

i have file inside document directory and i want to add some text (it'l be a string in JSON format) to this file. As of now i'm using below line of code to write to the file but it is overriding the file every time i write to it. So is there a better way to handle this situation ? i'm new to swift and can't seem to find a solution.

```
stringVariable.writeToFile(self.directoryPath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

As it is going to be a file with JSON String's in it, how to check if the text already has some data and assign or remove "," (Comma) from the end of the Json String?

Initially the file contains some text like

```
{ "documentComments":[]}
```

My JSON String is like as follows,

```
{ "comment": "MySecondComment", "commentDate": "2015-04-23 17:58:59 +0000", "isSigned": 1, "accountId": 1, "documentId": 3 }
```

By inserting couple of json string i want the file to finally look like below,

```
{ "documentComments":[
{ "comment": "MyFirstComment", "commentDate": "2015-04-22 17:58:59 +0000", "isSigned": 0, "accountId": 1, "documentId": 2 },
{ "comment": "MySecondComment", "commentDate": "2015-04-23 17:58:59 +0000", "isSigned": 1, "accountId": 1, "documentId": 3 }]}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: this isn't really a text manipulation problem (unless you want to write your own JSON parser, which you shouldn't.) Read the JSON into the appropriate data structure, add stuff to that data structure and serialize it back to file.

Comment: actually i'm not trying to read this JSON, but create a JSON object from the user provided inputs on a document, that i have in my app. Basically i'm creating a file with all these "comment" JSON objects, in order to store them in server while the user is offline and writing comments on a document. When the user get's access to Internet there will be a sync button, and when the user click's on it i will run a read routine to read the JSONified comments from that file and save them on server. I hope i didn't make it sound complicated.

Comment: @Sashi JSON is the format you should use to store and restore your data structures/objects. Text is only what you present to the user, and what the user interacts with. Behind the scenes, use swift/cocoa objects and store/restore JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you seek to implement is prone to the following issues:

- either the JSON will be partially invalid on disk all the time (unterminated array & unterminated dictionary)
- or you will append the array & dictionary terminators before attempting to sync the file to the server but if the sync fails you will then be unable to append back to the file without removing the array/dictionary terminators
- you will have to manually escape every comments to make sure they do not contain JSON formatting characters

Because of this, as recommended by others, you should read the JSON file entirely from disk, append the comment to the in-memory array then encode/write the file back to disk. You gain:

- JSON file guaranteed to be valid at all times
- no need to manually escape characters, JSONEncoder will do that for you

If you find that read/modify/write is too slow, you could read the file once at startup, keep the cached data in the app at runtime, and encode/write the file to disk after every comment.

If that's still too slow for you, you could encode the final resulting file only before sync or before the app is terminated by the user/system.

This should work fine unless you expect the user to enter more than 500MB of text comments between each sync.  In which case you will likely want to send the comments in several smaller JSON files anyway to reduce risk of data transmission issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using below function:

```
func write(textToAppend: String, to fileName: String) {
    let fileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileURL.path) {
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            if let data = textToAppend.data(using: .utf8) {
                fileHandle.write(data)
            }
            fileHandle.closeFile()
        }
    } else {
        do {
            try textToAppend.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating file: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
```

How to use that function?

Just write like below:

```
write(textToAppend:"word 1", to: "debug.txt")
write(textToAppend:" word 2", to: "debug.txt")
```

After reading the file, output will be something like:

> word 1 word 2

Comment: While this does append to the end of the file, it doesn't solve the issue that the file created would likely not be valid JSON unless a final 'write' to the file is done just before syncing.  And if syncing fails and the app then appends again on the file it will no longer be valid JSON.

Comment: The author will also have the issue of ensuring the strings do not contain any JSON formatting characters such as quotation marks by escaping them in a JSON compatible format.

In the end, I think it will be much simpler and not much more expensive for the author to just read the JSON file from disk, append to the array and save the file back to disk.  If reading/writing is too long, the content could be cached in the app so reading only happens once.